# How to make independent push notification in Android & iOS devices?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

How to make independent push notification on mobile? By independent I mean not relying on Google Firebase cloud messaging. Since GCM was depreciated I would like to make a solution not dependent on mobile devices vendors.

Answer (score 1):

**Talking about Android in particular**

Using Push Notifications without using any Google's/Firebase service would be a bit tricky. Since GCM/FCM service, keep on running on the device at all times, hence there is guarantee that their notifications will definitely be delivered.

However, for your use case, if you really want to implement your own custom Push Notification Service, you can follow these steps:

1. Implement a background service which keeps on running in the background. Your service could be killed sometimes, due to various factors of the android device, hence, you may need to implement an `AlarmReceiver` to restart your service if it is killed, from time to time.
2. In your background service, you must either ping your server, at certain intervals, passing a unique ID, maybe a user Id, or device Id or any other uniquely identifiable ID for each device/user,  to check if there are any notifications or not. This could further be implemented in various ways, like using `Socket Connection`, or via `APIs` etc. You will have to find the best solution to minimize the number of requests on the server.
3. If there are any notifications, based on the passed (queried) `parameters`, the server should send the `response` with the content. Otherwise, do nothing.
4. Once you receive a valid (with content) `response` from the server, you can create a `notification` to remind the user about the same.

*Please note, this may not be the best solution to perfectly suit your requirements on both `Android` and `iOS`, however, this is a general process of receiving a notification from the server (implementing a two-way communication at certain intervals).*

You must focus on creating a service which keeps on running in the background at **almost** all times, to be able to use `push notifications` in real-time.

Comment: Yes, it should work in case of pinging a server in regular intervals and keeping a background service alive (like waking up after each restart of a mobile device). What in case if would like to make a message available to user just in time, Should use MQTT broker protocol to solve it?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use that. However, please note, that pinging server in regular intervals will result in higher load on the server too